# How to remove variables using loop

Tags: r

I have defined multiple variables on the global environment following the rule :

```
for (i in 1:999){
    assign(sprintf('Model%03d', i), something_i)
}
```

i.e., I generated variables `Model001`, `Model002`, ..., `Model999`.

But now I should remove those variables from the global environment.

---

#### What I tried

I tried the following

```
for (i in 1:999){
  rm(get(sprintf("Model%03d", i)))
}
```

But I got the following error

```
Error in rm(get(sprintf("Model%03d", i))) : 
  ... must contain names or character strings
```

Alternatively, I tried

```
for (i in 1:999){
  rm(sprintf("Model%03d", i))
}
```

but I have the same error message.

I would like to know a shortcut to do this task, even it is quite "dangerous" from the developer's point of view.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just do `rm(list  = sprintf("Model%03d", 1:999))`

Comment: @moreblue It is better not to generate so many objects. Put them in a list!